# CAKEPHP - how to leave the plug in url

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I have a ACL plugin, and I want to be able to redirect back to users/index from this plug in.. but I end up getting funny url's that don't exist. such as `/cakephp/admin/acl/users/index`

how can I make it go to `cakephp/users/index`

I have looked through the HTML helper and I'm stumped.

I will be in the [cakephp chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26939/cakephp) as well

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'reset' the plugin by setting it to 'false' when creating a link;

e.g.;

```
echo $this->Html->link('go to user overview', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'index',
    'plugin' => false
);
```

**update**

My guess is that you're using both  *prefix routing* and a *plugin*. To reset both the plugin and the prefix, do this;

```
echo $this->Html->link('go to user overview', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'index',
    'plugin' => false,      // resets the plugin
    'admin'  => false,      // resets the admin-prefix
);
```

Comment: it still keeps the admin part.. thus not working.. any other ideas?

Comment: My guess is that you're using both a plugin *and* prefix routing. I updated my answer with additional information